# Can I use a 78S05 regulator in place of 78L05?

Tags: voltage-regulator, short-circuit

I'm trying to do this circuit :

[image]

Can I use a 78S05 regulator instead of the 78L05? Or I need the 78L05 to realize this circuit.

Best regards

Comment: Ugh, wiring diagrams in place of schematics. Yes, probably. Check the datasheet for any catches like minimum loads or anything like that.

Comment: Be careful about the value of the capacitor. I suspect tis is really 4.7uF (4.7 microfarad). You have an extra 'm'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

78S05 Linear Voltage Regulators 5.0V 2.0A Positive  YES  OK

78L05 Linear Voltage Regulators 5.0V 0.1A Positive

But the output pullup resistor goes to your external supply and this should go the 5V regulator output instead.

[image]

Comment: Although in general it is acceptable to use the larger package part (78S05) in place of the low power version in this case I suspect the power is being supplied by a serial port with very limited capability - the quiescent current of the 78S05 is larger than that of the 78L05 and may be beyond the serial port's capability.

Comment: Good point But 7mA max  idle vs 5mA max idle on the L05 is not much different worst case but added to 5mA opto current and 1mA load , it wouldn't  fly on Output Resistance 300 Ω on RTS with 12mA*300 Ohm= 4.2V drop, so it would have to be a 10 to 12V RS232 RTS signal to work. and may need to be diode OR'd with pin 4 DTR.. So it is marginal poor replacement

Comment: And the sides of the 78S05 regulator must be like that? Thank you!

Comment: go find a 78L05 and remove resistor

Comment: I moved the  resistor as you specified and it work like charm! Thank you

Comment: as expected.  Glad to help

Answer (score 3):

Checkout [this](https://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/whats-the-differences-in-7805-voltage-regulators.106261/) forum on the same issue.

Looks like the difference is in the current rating. You will need to consult the datasheet on your IR receiver and determine it's needs, and verify the current running through is lower than the amount specified in the datasheet MAX.

Answer (score 1):

No that won't work.

the 78S05 uses too much current, (8mA, plus whatever the load wants) your serial port is unlikely to be able to provide enough to satisfy it.

Perhaps use a Zener diode instead:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM6fih.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: 0,6V vs 5V?  not a chance  Francesco